# How to make the Background behind Alert Box clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a application where i make all Divs clickable by using this code :

```
$("html").click(function(){
 alert("Click"); 
 return false;
});
```

This one work normally for all divs. Well, when Alert popup, the Background behind alert box cannot be clicked. How can i turn that to be clickable too?

PS: Right Click on the Background dont work too.

Comment: This is normal browser behaviour. When the alert is there, you cannot do anything but clicking the OK button on the alert.

Comment: this is not a good question...press ok and continuee

Comment: you unable to change the defoult alert box background  try to use popup javascript jquery  to make the  popup as per your requirent

Comment: Yes if you are using Javascript [alert('')] there is now way you can click its background that is also known as Modal Overlay.

Comment: sad! i wanted to individualize the Alert Box, so far we dont have to use jquery or other library into our product. Just raw Javascript. That's the reason why i wanted to customize the Alert Box.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not possible. You have to use a JS plugin doing the alert, so you can influence the behaviour (like the jquery ui modal widget, mentioned here). But with the browser alert this is not possible, as far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do exactly what you're asking (if it's possible). Maybe someone else can shed some light on that.

But a solution you could look into would be the dialog widget from jQuery UI. You can easily create pop-ups, modal or non-modal (meaning with the background faded out or not).

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/
They have some demos there, but it's as simple as created a div with some text and calling...

```
$("#the_div_id").dialog();
```

Other config parameters can be found from the API:
http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

By default its modal popup behaviour ,If you want to clickable

Assuming you are using Jquery Ui dialog

Try with the option modal

```
 $('#selector').dialog("option","modal",false);
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal